# Increasing thickness of PCB layers

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

To what values can I increase the thickness of each layer to be able to reach a total thickness of 1.6mm? Is there a specific standard between relative thicknesses for the dielectric layer, signal layer, and solder mask?

[image: PCB Layers]

Comment: To all of the answers below I will add: unless you care about tightly controlling trace impedances, you don't care about the exact layer thicknesses.  And if you don't know what a controlled trace impedance is, then you either don't need it, or you're in over your head anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For a 2-layer board, you can just specify the overall thickness as 1.6 mm or 63 mil, and the vendor will choose the correct dielectric thickness. Typically there is a +/- 10% tolerance on the board thickness, so specifying it to a tenth of a mil won't change the end result anyway.

You can specify the dielectric thickness as "as required" if you have the overall thickness specified elsewhere. Or in a 4-layer board you can specify the middle layer as "as required" if you have specified the overall thickness and the thickness of the other layers.

Answer (score 1):

You get this information from your PCB manufacturer. These values are not standardised, and will depend where the manufacturer sources their components from. Here's an example from [Aisler](https://aisler.net/help/design-rules-and-specifications/2-layer-hd-pcb-stackup).

[image]

For batch PCB services (Aisler, OSHPark, JLCPCB etc) you're unlikely to be able to specify what materials you get. For orders where it is just your design, the manufacturer may offer a choice of materials for you.

Comment: Do you recommend any PCB fabrication services?

Comment: @Kevin - personally, I use Aisler for batches and usually Eurocircuits for individual orders, but really depends where you are and what your priorities are.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty common is 0,5 - 1oz inner layers (1oz=0.035mm) and 1-2oz outer layers.
Every mass manufacturer has its "PCB Capabilities" on web pages.

Answer (score 0):

How much are you prepared to pay?

While something wild like 12oz copper is a thing is is a very specialist sort of thing.

The rules are basically that the stackup must be symmetrical (Well, must is a bit strong, but that is the way to bet), and usually you will want to use your preferred vendors standard cores and prepregs unless doing something weird and very expensive.